# How would I wrap my text using canvas?

Tags: javascript, css, canvas, html5-canvas

I am trying to wrap my text if the text line if above a certain number of pixels wide.  I have the text to where it'll print to the console if it is over the max width I want it to be(I did this for testing purposes) but I'm clueless as to how to get the text to wrap.  Can anyone help or point me in the right direction?

```
var text = result[0].text;
var max_text_width = 150;
ctx.font = text.font;
ctx.textAlign = text.align;
ctx.fillStyle = text.color;
for(var i = 0; i < text.fill.length; i++){
    var metrics = ctx.measureText(text.fill[i]);
    var text_width = metrics.width;
    if(text_width > max_text_width){
        ctx.fillText(text.fill[i], text.x[i], text.y[i]);
    }
    else{
        ctx.fillText(text.fill[i], text.x[i], text.y[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`<canvas>` is intended for graphics and does not provide very sophisticated text printing tools. An usual approach is to have an transparent `<div>` over `<canvas>` and use JavaScript DOM API and CSS to lay out your text elements over canvas (if feasible for use case).

If DOM is no go there are two options

- Write your own test layout code, e.g. [looking example from here](https://thiscouldbebetter.wordpress.com/2014/06/06/text-layout-and-justification-on-an-html5-canvas/)
- There are some libraries for advanced `<canvas>` based text manipulation, see [Zebra](http://www.zebkit.com/), [CanvasText](http://www.canvastext.com/)

However because `<canvas>` lacks APIs for accurate text and character tracking and styling, DOM based methods will be superior what comes to available effects and render output.

Comment: This is better posted as a comment or alternatively post the appropriate code from the links you site.